# Loop through multiple nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I need to calculate a variable, 'remaining inventory' by looping through the following two dictionaries and subtracting `sales_demand` from 'current_inventory'.

The dictionaries do not however, share the same keys. i.e. on some days there are no sales therefore demand is 0 ('2020-02-29' for example)

How can I loop through the dictionaries to produce this output without raising a `KeyError` as a result of the missing keys?

Data below:

```
# Current inventory 
inventory = {'2020-02-28':{'ASF': 220102,
                           'MFA': 100109,
                           'PRE': 218256},
             '2020-03-29':{'ASF': 321200,
                           'MFA': 151505,
                           'PRE': 175000},
             '2020-03-01':{'ASF': 312765,
                           'MFA': 300021,
                           'PRE': 118561},
             '2020-03-02':{'ASF': 121203,
                           'MFA': 209909,
                           'PRE': 210000}}
# Sales Demand
sales = {
  '2020-02-28':{
    'CEYLON':{
      'ASF': 55000,
      'MFA': 0,
      'PRE': 0
     },
    'PACIFIC MAJOR':{
      'ASF': 100000,
      'MFA': 0,
      'PRE': 0
     },
    'CCSC YASA JING':{
      'ASF': 10000,
      'MFA': 6000,
      'PRE': 18000
     }},
  '2020-03-01':{
    'ABC':{
      'ASF': 0,
      'MFA': 0,
      'PRE': 65000},
    'DEF etc':{
      'ASF': 0,
      'MFA': 19191,
      'PRE': 0}},
  '2020-03-02':{
    'ABC':{
      'ASF': 75000,
      'MFA': 10000,
      'PRE': 0},
    'DEF etc':{
      'ASF': 55000,
      'MFA': 55000,
      'PRE': 0}}}
```

Expected outcome:

```
remaining_inventory = {}

for date in dates:
  for vessel in vessels:
    for grade in grades:
      remaining_inventory[date][grade] = current_inventory[date][grade] - sales[date][vessel][grade]
```

Note - I need to keep track of each sale i.e. product leaving inventory to go to each vessel so cannot simply aggregate the total sales demand for each day, grade.

Comment: If looking for a more elegant solution, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: kindly post the expected outcome

Comment: @simic0de: I need a working solution before I improve it.

Comment: @sammywemmy I have edited my post - hopefully this makes it clearer? thank you.

Comment: @cmp, you did not add an expected output. It should be in the same form as your input. It will guide whoever submits a solution to your challenge

Comment: @sammywemmy, apologies - I understand. Since this is an optimisation problem, I am trying to formulate a 'remaining_inventory' variable for each date, rather than create an output dataframe/dict etc, if that makes sense? I have added more context however.

Comment: Your sample data is unhelpful. Numbers are repeated so often it obscures the source of any particular expected result. To get a helpful answer, perhaps consider recasting as "I want this input <...> to give me this ouput <...>".

Comment: @holdenweb - Thank you for pointing out - I have changed the values to reflect the correct inputs/outputs. Hopefully the expected output comment is self-explanatory however?

Comment: The "expected output" would show enough of the expected result for readers to be able to verify their solution meets your expectations. Consider this a small debugging exercise on your question ;-)

Comment: Also I'd recommend, if you have control over the data format, to omit the keys with zero values, since they add nothing to the information the structure contains.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your desired output and you will also have to give some clarification on what the abreviations mean to better understand what you want to do in the loops.

To avoid the KeyError, I see two options

- If you know that keys will always be present in one dictionary and sometimes in the other, loop over the dictionary that might contain the key. So if it's in this smaller dictionary then it's always in the other and there will be no KeyError.
- If keys are sometimes present in one dictionary and sometimes in the other, it's better to loop over one dictionary's keys and do something like this:

```
for key in first_dict:
     if key in second_dict.keys():
         do_something()
```

EDIT: I think this is what you want to do, but I'm not 100% sure:

```
for date in sales:
    remaining_inventory[date] = {}
    for vessel in sales[date]:
        for grade in sales[date][vessel]:
             remaining_inventory[date][grade] = inventory[date][grade] - sales[date][vessel][grade]thing()
```

Output:

```
 {'2020-02-28': {'ASF': 210102, 'MFA': 94109,  'PRE': 200256}, 
  '2020-03-01': {'ASF': 312765, 'MFA': 280830, 'PRE': 118561}, 
  '2020-03-02': {'ASF': 66203,  'MFA': 154909, 'PRE': 210000}}
```

I added `remaining_inventroy[date] = {}` because you added a value to a dictionary that not yet existed.